# How to localize an iOS storyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, nslocalizedstring, uistoryboard

I've an iPhone storyboard with some views. For instance, a navigation item title is named `News`, which should be translated for other languages.

When I add a new localization to my storyboard, it created a duplicate of my current storyboard for the new language. Here I can change the title for the navigation item, but for me it does not seem very useful. What if my storyboard contains 100 views and I need to support 10 languages? If I need to change something in my original storyboard, I have to make the same changes for all languages. That seems very odd. In which situations can this be useful?

What can I do instead? Should I have only the english storyboard and manually translate each element in the ViewController using `NSLocalizedString`?

Comment: @WTP: Rather, you should probably use *multiple* storyboards if you have that many. 5 or 10 storyboards is certainly better than 100 xibs.

Comment: Check [Use single storyboard file for Base Internationalization in iOS 6](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1467446), you will find a detail way to do what you need.

Comment: take a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38631740/how-to-shift-all-uiview-from-left-to-right-in-ios-objective-c/38631847#38631847

Answer (score 109, accepted):

In iOS 6 there is a Project setting under the Info tab that says "Use Base Internationalization". If you check the box, it will pull all of the strings out of the Storyboard and into internationalized .strings files.

This way you don't have to have multiple copies of the Storyboard.

[image]

Comment: There is a good tutorial for this at http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1467446

Comment: How to update those strings files when contents of your storyboard change?

Answer (score 39):

As of iOS 6 you can decide to use Base Internationalization: All storyboard and xib/nib files exist only once in a folder named Base.lproj. The localization of the GUI elements is placed in related .strings files in each localization directory.

For example "MainStoryboard.storyboard" will be placed in Base.lproj. An associated file called "MainStoryboard.strings" is placed in en.lproj and whatever localization you apply.

This is really very handsome, especially in combination with layout constraints!

Comment: Does the Base Internationalization work with iOS 5 or 4? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately only iOS 6 and better. If you set iOS 5 as the target, you receive an error message.

Answer (score 11):

You can do the localization by changing the titles of the UI elements in code:

```
self.title = NSLocalizedString("News", nil);
```

If you want to localize your app in Dutch for example, you would have this in `Dutch.lproj/Localizable.strings`:

```
"News" = "Nieuws";
```

You can then do this for every UI element and language.

Comment: And if you need to do some resizing of the UI (such as when the translation is too long and gets truncated)? That's one thing that is easily done when localizing xib files rather than programmatically replacing text through NSLocalizedString. But I don't know if storyboards allow this (I haven't tried storyboards yet).

Comment: @Clafou You can put the sizes in the localizable strings and convert them to numbers at runtime.

Comment: The proposed solution doesn't work with UITabBar's lazy loading. `viewDidLoad:`  will be called first, when you tab on the matching tab bar item. So the app starts unlocalized.

Comment: This answer is out of date, and should no longer be accepted - see the answers from Collin and freytag below.

Answer (score 6):

You might find this video tutorial here useful:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cF1Rf02QvZQ

The approach is to have a separate storyboard for each language to localize,
then let a script take care of propagating the changes you make in the original storyboard
for all other languages.

Answer (score 3):

For apps with a deployment target of iOS 5 and storyboards I use something like this to localize my tabs where my first ViewController on a storyboard is a `UITabBarController`:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    // ...

    if ([self.window.rootViewController isKindOfClass:UITabBarController.class]) {
        UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *) self.window.rootViewController;

        // Localize tab items
        NSArray *tabBarItems = tabBarController.tabBar.items;

        [tabBarItems enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent 
                                      usingBlock:^(UITabBarItem *item, NSUInteger tabIndex, BOOL *stop) {
            NSString *keyName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tabBarItem%i", tabIndex];
            item.title = NSLocalizedString(keyName, @"TabBarItems");
        }];
    } else {
        // The root view controller is not the UITTabBarController
    }

    // ...
}
```

and have something like this in my `Localizable.strings` files:

```
// MARK: TabBar
"tabBarItem0" = "My First Tab Label";
"tabBarItem1" = "My Second Tab Label";
"tabBarItem2" = "My Third Tab Label";
```

Comment: This works, but knocked out the tab bar item icons until I added the following: [tabBarItems[0] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabIcon1.png"]]; etc., for each item in the tab bar

Answer (score 2):

You might find Polyglot Localization useful as well. In stead of calling NSLocalizedString() in code, you can directly specify the key it in your Storyboard. You can avoid unnecessary outlets and reduce boilerplate code.

https://github.com/negusoft/Polyglot

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you learn  the commandline ibtool it helps asist you in localizing all of your storyboards :) Here is a tutorial here http://www.albertmata.net/articles/introduction-to-internationalization-using-storyboards-on-ios-5.html

Comment: I believe that this is the way to go for storyboard localization!

Comment: the link is dead try http://www.lwxted.com/blog/2012/localization-ios-development/  check this application https://github.com/EldhoseIssac/LocalizationHelper to help localization

Comment: @Experiments that link is bad too.